# Search across all namespaces in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way for me to search across all the  namespaces in google app engine? Conceptually its not possible but wanted to check with the community.

Currently, I iterate through all namespaces and query each of them. Its time consuming and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with standard datastore queries. Options would be to use Search API, or export to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as Gwyn is pointing out.  I DO see that there is a bug for this feature to be added in Google's Public Issue Tracker (namely, [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4120))

Answer (score 0):

It's also not possible using the Search API.  My understanding is that namespaces are designed for isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the same search document to two index. One generic or default and other isolated.

Then just search over the generic one, for example:

```
generic = search.Index("all_docs")
specific = search.Index("specific", namespace="sample_namespace")

generic.put("search_document")
specific.put("search_document")
```